# attempting to split string dynamically keep getting error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm attempting to split a string I'm passing into

```
$("#groupUL").append("<li>" + "<h2>About Item:</h2> " + response.data[i].message + "<br /> " + "<h2>Posted By:</h2> <a href='#' onclick='splitName('" + response.data[i].from.name + "');'>" + response.data[i].from.name + "</a>" +  "<br />");
```

Seems to be passing me the error

```
SyntaxError: syntax error

splitName(
```

Not sure how that's wrong...Here is the splitname function if that helps

```
function splitName(txt){
    var myString = txt;

    var mySplitResult = myString.split(" ");

    console.log("The first element is " + mySplitResult[0]); 
    console.log("<br /> The second element is  " + mySplitResult[1]); 
    console.log("<br /> The third element is  " + mySplitResult[2]); 

};
```

Comment: Are you sure it is `from` there?

Comment: count the quotes in `onclick='splitName('" + response.data[i].from.name + ");'>`

Comment: Where? Not seeing where I'm missing  a quote and yes it's saying it's after the ( in splitName(

Comment: Dystroy, that was typo still passing error when I put the ' between " and )

Comment: This is a great example of why not to use `onclick`.  Instead, apply the handler using `.on()`, and you will avoid this mess, as well as a number of other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only problem with your code is with your readability issue. So I would suggest please improve it. Lets have a look at it. [My code example](http://jsbin.com/awayuf/2/edit) @ JSbin.

Here is the code :- (which i think is better)

```
var response = {
  data : {
    message: 'Cleaning code',
    from: {
      name: 'Clean Code works'
    }
  }
};


var li = $('<li>'); //Create empty li (Not Appending to DOM now due to performance issues)

$('<h2>').html('About Item:' + response.data.message + '<br />').appendTo(li);
$('<h2>').html('Posted By:').appendTo(li);
$('<a>').attr('href', '#')
  .html(response.data.from.name)
  .appendTo(li)
  .click(function() {
    splitName(response.data.from.name);
  });

$('<br>').appendTo(li);

// Append li to ul (Final operation to DOM)
li.appendTo('#groupUL');

function splitName(txt){
    var myString = txt;

    var mySplitResult = myString.split(" ");

    console.log("The first element is " + mySplitResult[0]); 
    console.log("The second element is  " + mySplitResult[1]); 
    console.log("The third element is  " + mySplitResult[2]); 
}
```

Comment: What did u mean by not appending to dom? Will try utilizing something with this type of structure and let you know results, thanks!

Comment: I am glad, You asked this. You know DOM operation is performance heavy so we should try to minimize the number of DOM operations. If we append li to dom at initial stage, any change to li will cause an operation on DOM and will affect the performance. So it is a better practice to do all your operations on cached object and then make final update to DOM.

Comment: TypeError: response.data[i] is undefined
[Break On This Error]  



...$('<h2>').html('About Item:' + response.data[i].message + '<br />').appendTo(li)


main.js (line 248)


TypeError: response.data[i] is undefined
[Break On This Error]  


...$('<h2>').html('About Item:' + response.data[i].message + '<br />').appendTo(li)


main.js (line 248)


TypeError: response.data[i] is undefined
[Break On This Error]  


splitName(response.data[i].from.name);


http://pastebin.com/TvNTJRst

Comment: @user2122206 this simply means your response object is not having data array. Basically, your response.data[i] is undefined. Please check your response. There is nothing wrong with this code.

Answer (score 2):

It's too hard to get it right when you put quotes in quotes in quotes and you try to escape it right. You got it wrong.

A solution is to make it in small parts :

```
var action = "splitName('" + response.data[i].from.name + "');";
$("#groupUL").append("<li>" + "<h2>About ... onclick=\""+action+"\">...");
```

But the best solution would be to follow best practice, that is not inline the javascript but use jQuery's binding function :

```
$("#groupUL").append("... <a id=myid ..."); 
$("#myid").click(function(){ splitName(response.data[i].from.name) });
```